# What is git diff [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path>

Tags: git

Can someone explain to me me what git diff [] --no-index [--]   does? Why are we comparing two different local path directories on my computer. What is there to compare between 2 folders, I could not understand it from the documentations.

Comment: What is there to compare? It could be anything.... say, just off the top of my head: 2 different revisions of a project where you only have the src.gz. You can unpack the sources to two different dirs and then compare to see what changed.... but it could be just about anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Normally with `git diff`, you're comparing two separate states of the repository, which can include the working tree, the index, or one or more revisions.  However, sometimes people want to compare two paths that are not in a repository using `git diff`, and the `--no-index` flag allows that.

You can do much of this with the plain `diff` command, but `git diff` is more powerful in many ways, and many people prefer using it in these cases.

An example of this kind of use with plain `diff` using two directories is when a user makes a copy of a directory, makes changes in one of the copies, and then generates a diff between the two directories with `-R`, which recursively lists all the changes between the two directories.  This was the traditional way to send a patch to a software project for a long time, and `git diff --no-index` can perform the same actions.